# What are good cases not to use setReatinInstance(true) in a fragment?

Tags: android

Since orientation changes happen fairly quickly one would think that keeping a `Fragment` in memory during that time would be more efficient than recreating it again. 
Since it's kept for a short time only, there seem to be little impact on memory.

What then shall be good reasons NOT to use `setRetainInstance(true)` for each and every `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What then shall be good reasons NOT to use setRetainInstance(true) for each and every Fragment?

Google's primary concern is that you'll screw up and have data members in the fragment that refer to the old activity that you do not clean up in post-configuration lifecycle method calls (e.g., `onCreateView()`). For example, you might hold onto a widget in a data member, where you do not immediately `null` out or repopulate that data member on a configuration change. If your fragment has a reference back to the old activity, the old activity (and everything it holds onto) cannot be garbage-collected until your fragment gets destroyed. This is one of the reasons why Google does not recommend retaining any fragment with a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly maybe check this link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-setretaininstancetrue-affect.html

Basically you shouldn't always retain the instance of the fragment because fragments are attached to activities. Hence when an activity is re-created (i.e. on configuration change), the fragment needs to be re-associated to the new activity (which leads to extra coding and some extra problems). If you just unnecessarily setRetainInstance(true), you are giving yourself more error checking and coding to do for no reason. By setting the setRetainInstance(true), you will need to deal with a different fragment lifecycle as well because certain methods in the lifecyle are now skipped (i.e. the onCreate() is no longer called after configuration changes). As far as I understand, setRetainInstance(true), won't make it more efficient because you could use onSaveInstance to save any data that you would want to use in the recreation of the same kind of fragment.

I hope this helps.